# Listen to UDP Socket in Background using GCDAsyncUdpSocket

Tags: background-task, gcdasyncsocket, background-mode

I have one application that connects to a network device (in LAN) over UDP and listen for new messages using GCDAsyncUdpSocket. It works fine in foreground but in background it is not able to respond.  I want to show a local notification when I receive a message from UDP. Please suggest how we can achieve this by following Apple policies.

Thanks & Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

All sockets are set to sleep when the app is in background.

The option you have is to do [Fetching Small Amounts of Content Opportunistically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56)

In case your app is a VoIP app, you can keep a TCP socket live and the OS will inform you when data is received. This way you can set a "wake up" message to be sent over TCP and then use UDP for the actual data transfer.